# I raise two validationerror but if anyone of them is triggered it always gives me the same validation error output

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I raised two validationerror messages but if anyone is triggered it gives me the same message of one of the the message is "User has already a current profile model try to update it not creating a new one"

here is the code

```
    class CurrentProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CurrentProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user', )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            c_profile = CurrentProfile(**validated_data)
            if c_profile.profile.owner != c_profile.user:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('You can only use profiles that the user created')
            c_profile.save()
            return c_profile
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User has already a current profile model try to update it not creating a new one')
```

the try and except block is made because i mad a OneToOne realtionship in my model CurrentProfile with the user model so it will trigger an error if i tried to add more than one instance of the CurrentProfile Model with same user.
the validation error in the if block is made to ensure that the profile selected is created by the same user not just any random profile created by another user

the weird thing is that if i remove the try and except block it works fine but when add it again in both cases it gives me the same validation error message which is "User has already a current profile model try to update it not creating a new one" even though if the user have no CUrrentProfile instance and is just trying to select profile that is not his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're raising an error from inside your `try` block, which is making it always go into the `except` block and raise the error there. Try this, instead:

```py
  class CurrentProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CurrentProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user', )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        c_profile = CurrentProfile(**validated_data)

        if c_profile.profile.owner != c_profile.user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You can only use profiles that the user created')

        try:
            c_profile.save()
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User has already a current profile model try to update it not creating a new one')

        return c_profile
```